# SQL If statement - check if row count of subquery = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any suggestions on how to do this?  I have a complex if statement in a query that needs to check on various conditions for a given table.  EG:

```
IF EXISTS  (SELECT Labeler
  FROM [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
  where Lname like '@Lname' AND Approved = 0 AND Access = 'P')
      
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Labeler
  FROM [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
  where Lname like '@Lname' AND Approved = 1)

  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT Labeler
  FROM [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
  where Lname like '@Lname' AND Approved = 2)


    RETURN 1
ELSE...
```

However, for that first subquery, I also need to make sure it only yields one row.  Exists just checks for 1 or more rows, but how do I constrain it to only return 1 if that first subquery has ONLY one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically need *exactly* one row, you can use aggregation:

```
IF 1 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
        WHERE Lname like '@Lname' AND Approved = 0 AND Access = 'P'
       ) AND . . .
```

I strongly recommend `EXISTS` when you just need to check existence, because it is faster than aggregation.

Comment: If there are a large amount of rows then we can subquery with a `TOP(2)` to get an early bail-out

Answer (score 1):

This query can be simplified to access the `[xx].[dbo].[manuf]` table only once:

```
IF 1 = (
  select 1
  from [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
  where Lname like '@Lname'
    and Approved in (0, 1, 2)
  having
    /*There's only one row, that is approved = 0 and access = 'P'*/
    sum(case when Approved = 0 and Access = 'P' then 1 end) = 1
    /*And there's no rows with Approved > 0*/
    and max(Approved) = 0
)

  RETURN 1
...
```

*db<>fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=720069f7f2c44cf7b16bcff44af7bf9d)*.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY Labeler ORDER BY x)
FROM [xx].[dbo].[manuf]
where Lname like '@Lname' AND Approved = 0 AND Access = 'P'
```

Then check to see if `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: `row_number()` need an `over` clause. Also this doesn't show how to test that there is exactly one row?